# placing three background images in same position

Tags: jquery, html, css, image, position

I have three images img1.png, img2.png, img3.png with heights 600px,400px and 200px respectively. I want to place these images in same position such as img1.png in back, img2.png in middle and img3.png in front. I tried with css position attributes, but not working. I have placed images as background for three div's:

```
<div id="clouds1"></div>
<div id="clouds2"></div>
<div id="clouds3"></div>

<style>

#clouds1
{
    background:url('images/img1.png');
    height:600px;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:1;
}

#clouds2
{
   background:url('images/img2.png');
   height:400px;
   position:relative;
   z-index:8;

}

#clouds3
{
   background:url('images/img3.png');
   height:200px;
   position:relative;
   z-index:99;
}

</style>
```

How can we do this with css position attribute or using another method. please help. Thank you

Comment: can you show what you have tried?using attr?

Comment: question updated with postion attr.. please check

Comment: your div has ID in your css you use class?try using absolute for all your style

Comment: @user1693763 all 3 of your `div` needs to be absolute for it to work. See the example answer I provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want something like this. Just add `position:absolute` & `z-index`:

```css
div#a {background-color:green;width:50px;height:10px;position:absolute;z-index:3;}
div#b {background-color:red;width:50px;height:30px;position:absolute;z-index:2;}
div#c {background-color:black;width:50px;height:50px;position:absolute;z-index:1;}
```

```html
<div id="a"></div>
<div id="b"></div>
<div id="c"></div>
```

You can change the z-index to show which `div` tag that you want to show in front, which `div` to be in the middle etc.

If you don't know what z-index does, here is an example when I set the black `div` to `z-index:3`. As you can see they are all in the same position but the black `div` is now in front of the other 2:

```css
div#a {background-color:green;width:50px;height:10px;position:absolute;z-index:2;}
div#b {background-color:red;width:50px;height:30px;position:absolute;z-index:1;}
div#c {background-color:black;width:50px;height:50px;position:absolute;z-index:3;}
```

```html
<div id="a"></div>
<div id="b"></div>
<div id="c"></div>
```

Another extra thing mentioned by @gibberish is that the outer element which contains all 3 `div` should be `position:absolute` or `position:relative`. This is because the default `position` value for any html element when not specified explicitly is `static`.

Comment: You should mention that `position:absolute` requires that the parent container (containing the a,b,c divs) is `position:relative` or `position:absolute` -- it cannot be left at the default `position:static`. Otherwise, an excellent, clear and well-written answer - +1

Comment: Thanks, I've added it to the answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can set position of the three `DIVs` to `absolute` and set their `top` & `left` to the same values, like this:

```
#clouds1, #clouds2, #clouds3 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px; <!-- change to fit your need -->
    left: 0px; <!-- change to fit your need -->
}
```

Or, if you just want to have one `DIV`, you can set multiple background images for that one DIV, like this.

```css
.three_backgrounds {
  background: url('http://images.clipartpanda.com/free-clipart-flowers-ncByRqpcA.png') top left no-repeat, url('http://worldartsme.com/images/pink-flower-vector-clipart-1.jpg') top left no-repeat, url('http://www.clker.com/cliparts/t/G/0/p/H/d/flower-hi.png') top left no-repeat;
  background-size: 100px 100px, 50px 50px, 70px 70px;
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div class="three_backgrounds">
</div>
```